# Move to Next Activity on Button click

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons in fragment and on button click, they displays Toast but I want move to another activity.

Here's my code...

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
        Button btn,btn2;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                                 ViewGroup container, 
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, 
                                         container, false);
            btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            btn2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.btn:
                    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),
                            "Button 1!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    break;
                case R.id.btn2:
                    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),
                            "Button 2 !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Heh. you get a toast because that's what you have on your button listener.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Use Intent for navigation***

Replace:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn:
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),YourDestinationActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);    
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),YourDestinationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**Replace these lines in place of toast and run your code:**

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),YourDestinationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```